SMS not sending automatically
i need a sms message to be sent automatically with the coordinates of location when the temperature is higher or lower than a certain range, although it tells in the debug console that the sms is sent but i receive nothing on the phone.
using gemini, i think the problem maybe that the sms is being sent every second when the condition is met, so i tried the below code, but it stills doesn't send the sms to the phone
i use the package background_sms 0.0.4
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Future<void> _getPermission() async {
    var status = await Permission.sms.status;
    if (!status.isGranted) {
      await Permission.sms.request();
    }
  }

  Future<bool> _isPermissionGranted() async =>
      await Permission.sms.status.isGranted;

  Future<bool?> get _supportCustomSim async =>
      await BackgroundSms.isSupportCustomSim;
  double temp = 0;
  double lat = 0;
  double lng = 0;
  Timer? _timer;
  bool _isTimerRunning = false;

  void _startTimer() async {
    if (!_isTimerRunning) {
      _isTimerRunning = true;
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(minutes: 2));
      if (temp > 24 || temp < 15) {
        if ((await _supportCustomSim)!) {
          _sendMessage("xxxxxxxxxxx",
              "Alert: Temperature at $temp°C,\nlocation: (latitude: $lat , longitude: $lng)",
              simSlot: 2);
        } else {
          await _getPermission();
        }
        _isTimerRunning = false;
      } else {
        _isTimerRunning = false;
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final fetch = Fetch();
    fetch.getTemperatureStream().listen((temperature) {
      setState(() {
        temp = temperature;
        _timer?.cancel();
        _startTimer();
      });
    });
    fetch.getLatitudeStream().listen((latitude) {
      setState(() {
        lat = latitude;
      });
    });
    fetch.getLatitudeStream().listen((longitude) {
      setState(() {
        lng = longitude;
      });
    });
  }```

